# Regex expression to validate for dollar amount

Tags: regex

I am trying to validate dollar amount , i need help with regular expression

anything greater than equal to 0.1.

for example

- 0.0 - fail
- 0  - fail
- 1 - pass
- 0.1 - pass
- 9999 - pass

any thoughts?

Comment: Why are you using regex for this? Seems like a simple if statement would suffice.

Comment: You're trying to validate a *value* with regex, not just a *pattern*?  I think you need to convert to a number and use `>=` instead.

Comment: I JavaScript 0 (zero) is falsy, so and if-statement fails. Boolean(0) -> false. May this helps you.

Comment: **Regular expressions are for matching patterns, not checking numeric values.** Find a likely string with the regex, then check its numeric value in whatever your host language is (PHP, whatever).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the pattern you need is a part of a larger pattern, you can use:

```
0\.[1-9]\d*|[1-9]\d*(\.\d*)?
```

Answer (score 0):

May you can use this regexp:

```
/^0[.]?[1-9]+$|^[1-9]+[.]?[0-9]+$|^[1-9]+$/.test('1.2');
```

or you do it the other way around:

```
/^0[.]0$|^0$/.test('0.0'); // return true when number is 0.0 or 0
```

I hope this helps you.